# How could I approach building a Tile based Map Editor in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to build a Tile-based Map Editor in #C Winforms. My main concern is drawing the tiles. In what space should I draw the tiles? Within a Panel? A Picture Box?

Also, I obviously need to draw textures over the tiles too. Does this mean my tiles need to have a pictureBox component? Or can I do this some other way?

I apologize if this is too broad a question. I've been researching but I can't exactly find the info I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: You should first start with simplest solution you can think off. Using panel with multiple picture boxes might work for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Panel` and then override its `OnPaint` method.

[Overriding the OnPaint Method (MSDN WinForms)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cksxshce(v=vs.110).aspx)

The `OnPaint` method will receive a `PaintEventArgs` argument, which will contain a property that is a `System.Drawing.Graphics`. You will be drawing everything by calling methods on this object.

[Graphics.DrawImage methods (MSDN System.Drawing)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage(v=vs.110).aspx)

This requires you to do some coordinate calculations that involve scaling (multiplications) and cropping (coordinate translations).